# How many bytes does a data type of FLOAT(10,6) take up in a database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to determine the size of a row in a table of a MySQL database. I am wondering how many bytes does a data type of FLOAT(10,6) take up in a database?

Comment: It is a MySQL database sorry

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Yes i had seen that but was confused by 4 bytes if 0 <= p <= 24, 8 bytes if 25 <= p <= 53

Comment: (However for money better use DECIMAL.) as 4 byte floats are quite imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

4 bytes. FLOAT(10, 6) is a non-standard syntax that defines how it'll be displayed. but it's still a float.

More precisely, a datatype FLOAT(M, D) will be single precision (32 bits) if 0<=M<=23, or double precision floating point if 24<=M<=53.

D specifies how many digits may be displayed after decimal dot (but it's independent of the number actually stored).

So, depending on M, it may take 4 or 8 bytes.

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html)